# What are these "keys" in bash script?

Tags: bash

I'm interested in:

```
if [ -z "${var// }" ]...

if [ -d $dir ]...
```

More precisely, what is -z and -d? How can I call it and where can I read about this "keys"? And where can i find a full list of this "keys"?

Comment: try the documentation: `man bash`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-z variable` will check condition if a variable is NULL then the condition will be TRUE if NOT then it will go to `else` part of `if` condition.

`-d directory_name` will check if a directory name which is given next to it is present or not. If directory is present then condition will be TRUE or it will be FALSE.

From `man test`

> -z STRING
>
> the length of STRING is zero
>
> -d FILE
>
> FILE exists and is a directory

Answer (score 1):

Look at the manpage for `test`

```
man test
```

Comment: Or `help test` for the built-in `test`. :-)

Comment: or `man [`, since "[" is actually the command being used here (which happens to be synonymous with the `test` command).

Answer (score 1):

in bash manual invoked using

```
 man -a bash
```

a section called `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` which covers what you are looking for, in fact there are a whole bunch of basic to advanced concepts in there to look for.